# Populate checkbox and label attributes from array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I trying to achieve something where I can populate few attributes for 4 checkboxes and label from specific arrays.
I don't want to append the entire markup. I am keeping everything on markup then need to feel-up the attributes based on the select menu selection.

```js
var _select = $('#opt');
var _container = $('#teams');

var FF1 = [{
        display: "Week 1",
        value: "Week-1"
    },
    {
        display: "Week 2",
        value: "Week-2"
    },
    {
        display: "Week 3",
        value: "Week-3"
    },
    {
        display: "Week 4",
        value: "Week-4"
    }
];

var FF2 = [{
        display: "Week 5",
        value: "Week-5"
    },
    {
        display: "Week 6",
        value: "Week-6"
    },
    {
        display: "Week 7",
        value: "Week-7"
    },
    {
        display: "Week 8",
        value: "Week-8"
    }
];


_select.on('change', function() {
    var parent = $(this).val();
    _container.removeClass('is-hidden');

    switch (parent) {
        case 'FF1':
            weekList(FF1);
            break;
        case 'FF2':
            weekList(FF2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

});

function weekList(array_list) {
    $(array_list).each(function(i) {
        console.log(array_list[i]);

    });
}
```

```css
.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="opt">
 <option value="">Select Option</option>
   <option value="FF1">FF1</option>
   <option value="FF2">FF2</option>
</select>

<div id="teams" class="is-hidden">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="teams" class="ck1" id="" />
        <label for="" class="lb1"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="teams" class="ck2" id="" />
        <label for="" class="lb2"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="teams" class="ck3" id="" />
        <label for="" class="lb3"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="teams" class="ck4" id="" />
        <label for="" class="lb4"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help me here?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: You need to create checkbox code inside the jQuery.

Comment: thanks, Jitendra, Yes, but I am stuck with filling data from arrays.

Comment: the structure will the same. I don't need to append entirely markup.

Comment: Here is the fiddle also - https://jsfiddle.net/3g4296on/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code may help, just replace the loop in function weekList().

```
$(array_list).each(function (i) {
    var Id = (i + 1)
    $('.ck' + Id).val(array_list[i].value);  // update checkbox values
    $('.ck' + Id).attr("id", ("ck"+ Id));    // update checkbox id
    $('.lb' + Id).text(array_list[i].display)// update label text
    $('.lb' + Id).attr("for",("ck"+ Id))     // update label for text
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Jitendra. It's working but didn't understand this "+ (i + 1)". Could you please explain?

Comment: also "ID" for checkbox and "FOR" for the label is not populating. I have updated the fiddle with your code - https://jsfiddle.net/3g4296on/9/

Comment: Code updated. Now about (i +1), as you know the array index will start from zero index and you have assign selector class(**ck1**) as `<input type="checkbox" class="ck1"/>` so when loop execute, first it will look for "chk0" because of array index start from zero, there are no such type of HTML control with chk0. I have added (i+1) so it will look for chk1, chk2, chk3...

Comment: Done Jitendra. Thanks Mate

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

```
function weekList(array_list) {
  var boxes = '';
  $(array_list).each(function(i) {

    boxes += `
                <div class="">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="${array_list[i]['value']}" class="ck1" value="${array_list[i]['value']}" />
                  <label for="${array_list[i]['value']}" class="lb1">${array_list[i]['display']}</label>
                </div>
            `;

  });

  document.getElementById('teams').innerHTML = boxes;
}
```

html-

```
<select id="opt">
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
  <option value="FF1">FF1</option>
  <option value="FF2">FF2</option>
</select>

<div id="teams">

</div>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Thanks, Akshay. I don't need to append any markup. Only attributes updates.

Comment: It's a markup code. Try to update code as per question.

Comment: see what you need is when you select option FF1 then the display from the array will be label and value will be checkbox value... right? then try this code...it will generate the html with desired attributes... no matter you only update attributes or get the html which already has